# Generate test ASP.NET Core test Result inside a Docker Volume with Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I am developing on a Windows 10 Pro machine, trying to generate the Microsoft trx test result file from within a docker container running in Linux mode.

This is my docker-compose yml file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis

  Project.Test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Project.Test/Dockerfile
```

This is the Dockerfile executed with the up command

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY Project.Test/*.csproj Project.Test/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202 Project.Test/*.csproj

COPY . ./

WORKDIR /src/Project.Test
RUN dotnet build Project.Test.csproj -c Release -o /app
RUN dotnet test --logger:trx;LogFileName=/artifacts/Project.Test.trx
```

I need to copy the Project.Test.trx on a folder on my Windows 10 machine but I am not able to correctly mount the volume.

What is the right command to insert inside the docker-compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to enable *Shared Drives* in the Docker for Windows settings (accessed via the system tray).

There is a section describing the process in detail available in the Docker docs https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives - which may require firewall rules and can be done either permanently (for all containers) or only when required when mounting a container.

There is also a useful troubleshooting section here, which will likely come in handy as there are a few related permission/firewall gotchas: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#volumes

Comment: The troubleshoot article helps me to detect that changing the domain domains passoword on the host, does not reflect the change on the docker engine settings. I had to reset credentials on it. By the way my scripts works!